# How to see nested exceptions trace, hidden by Spring?

Tags: eclipse, spring, debugging, exception, output

When I am debugging Spring application in Eclipse, I am getting long exception chains. For example, I have

```
Error creating bean with name '...' defined in file [...Tester.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property '...' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ...
```

And so on. Multiple stacks with exceptions inside Spring, which is uninteresting. It should be my exceptions somewhere below, but Spring does not show them.

And I can't click into exception and navigate to problem place as usual.

How to say Spring to output all exceptions?

**UPDATE**

Below is the full output. One can see that the place where `IllegalArgumentException` occurred was probably truncated.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mybean' defined in file [D:\mypath\myconfig.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'myproperty' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: my exception message
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at springtests.SpringRunner.main(SpringRunner.java:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'target.partner' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal frame length 1 in explicit constructor
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: It's not truncating the exception. That is what you get when you have nested exceptions.

Comment: Yes, these are nested exceptions. How to have them all displayed?

Comment: They *are* all displayed. Reading the stack trace can be confusing though. Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29

Comment: I posted full output. `IllegalArgumentException` was in my setter. Can you find it in the listing please if you sure all exceptions are there?

Comment: Ah! You're quite right. Because Spring is trying to set a load of properties at once, it's bunching up the nested exceptions.

Comment: Great! So, the question remains: how to see these hidden exceptions?

Comment: It wasn't me who voted you down by the way :-)

Comment: I know people are starting from downvotes

Answer (score 1):

Because there are potentially multiple exceptions, you need to catch the `PropertyBatchUpdateException` and call `getPropertyAccessExceptions()` to examine the stack trace of the particular exception.

Edit

Actually I'm not quite sure what's going on here

Here is `PropertyBatchUpdateException`'s `printStackTrace` method:

```
public void printStackTrace(PrintWriter pw) {
        synchronized (pw) {
            pw.println(getClass().getName() + "; nested PropertyAccessException details (" +
                    getExceptionCount() + ") are:");
            for (int i = 0; i < this.propertyAccessExceptions.length; i++) {
                pw.println("PropertyAccessException " + (i + 1) + ":");
                this.propertyAccessExceptions[i].printStackTrace(pw);
            }
        }
    }
```

It should be including the nested stack traces. Are you using the latest version of Spring?

Edit:

The best I can suggest is to run in debug mode, then put a breakpoint at `AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361` and see what's going on.

Comment: May be there are some Spring configs which may make it just display all it has?

Comment: Have you set Spring's logging config to DEBUG?

Comment: I don't know. I have my own `log4.properties` file in classpath with `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1`.

Comment: @Dims Do you see a load of Spring logging at debug level when you start it up?

Comment: Ah, yes, I see messages labelled `DEBUG` coming from Spring.